# Why does my regex in JavaScript return undefined?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all the matches for 'test' in my string:

```js
const search = "test";
const regexString = "(?:[^ ]+ ){0,3}" + "test" + "(?: [^ ]+){0,3}";
const re = new RegExp(regexString, "gi");
const matches = [];
const fullText = "my test string with a lot of tests that should match the test regex";
let match = re.exec(fullText);
while (match != undefined) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
    match = re.exec(fullText);
}
console.log(matches);
```

I'm getting the following:

```
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Why isn't my search working?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Trying to return an array containing the 3 words preceding and proceeding 'test'

Comment: Just to clarify, if `exec(..)` doesn't found a match it will return `null` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not an expert of regular expressions, but if you substitute matches.push(match[1]) with matches.push(match[0]) you obtain:
["my test string with a", "lot of test", "should match the test regex"]

Answer (score 4):

Your code expects the result of the match to include stuff captured in capturing groups in the regular expression. However, your regular expression contains only non-capturing groups. The `(?: )` grouping explicitly does *not* capture the matched substring.

You want plain `( )` groupings.

Comment: Thanks. When I change to: const regexString = "([^ ]+ ){0,3}" + "test" + "( [^ ]+){0,3}"; I get: [ 'my ', 'of ', 'the ' ]. Is there a way to capture a few words before and after the 'test' search search? Sorry for beginner question regex confuses me.

Comment: @Mary right - your code expects there to be something in `match[1]`, but if there are no real capturing groups `match` will always be an array with just one value. Your code currently only looks at `match[1]`, but the regular expression (fixed) captures *two* groups, so you need to also look at `match[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your non-capturing groups `(?:...)` in a capturing group `(...)` since you are invoking a capturing group (`match[1]`). :

```
"((?:\\S+ ){0,3})" + search + "((?: \\S+){0,3})"
```

> Trying to return an array containing the 3 words preceding and
>   proceeding 'test'

Then you need to push both captured groups not one:

```
matches.push([match[1], search, match[2]]);
// `match[1]` refers to first capturing group
// `match[2]` refers to second CG
// `search` contains search word
```

JS code:

```js
const search = "test";
const regexString = "((?:\\S+ ){0,3})" + search + "((?: \\S+){0,3})";
const re = new RegExp(regexString, "gi");
const matches = [];
const fullText = "my test string with a lot of tests that should match the test regex";
while ((match = re.exec(fullText)) != null) {
    matches.push([match[1], search, match[2]]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: This, however, doesn't output correct data on overlapping matches. A workaround would be using a lookahead construct.

Comment: Is worth mentioning that regex [doesn't support repeated capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461376/regex-repeating-capturing-group) so the best approach is to capture the three words (from before and after) together in a bigger capturing group.

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira It's not the regex, it's the flavor. i.e. `.NET` supports accessing to quantified capturing groups, each one individually.