# RegEx for matching first names in the middle of sentences

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to capture names in a paragraph, and return them as an array. The sentence with the names contains "`names are`". Example:

> The first sentence. Some second sentence. Third sentence and the names
>   are John, Jane, Jen. Here is the fourth sentence about other stuff.

#### Desired Output:

[ "John", "Jane", "Jen" ]

#### Attempt

```
paragraph.match(/names are ([A-Za-z ]+,{0,1} {0,1})+\./)
```

Comment: Related: [Regex - Repeating Capturing Group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43461376/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `names are ([^.]+)` to match everything until the next period. Then use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the names to an array

```js
const str = 'The first sentence. Some second sentence. Third sentence and the names are John, Jane, Jen. Here is the fourth sentence about other stuff.'

const regex = /names are ([^.]+)/,
      names = str.match(regex)[1],
      array = names.split(/,\s*/)

console.log(array)
```

Comment: You can also just use a negated character class instead of lazy matching: `([^.]+)\.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` after matching

```js
let str = `The first sentence. Some second sentence. Third sentence and the names are John, Jane, Jen. Here is the fourth sentence about other stuff.`

let res = str.match(/names are ([A-Za-z ]+,{0,1} {0,1})+\./g)[0].split(/\s+/g).slice(2)
console.log(res)
```