# Match group before nth character and after that

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match everything before the nth character (except the first character) and everything after it. So for the following string

```
/firstname/lastname/some/cool/name
```

I want to match

```
Group 1: firstname/lastname
Group 2: some/cool/name
```

With the following regex, I'm nearly there, but I can't find the correct regex to also correctly match the first group and ignore the first /:

```
([^\/]*\/){3}([^.]*)
```

Note that I always want to match the 3rd forward slash. Everything after that can be any character that is valid in an URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex group are not giving proper result because `([^\/]*\/){3}` you're repeating captured group which will overwrite the previous matched group [`Read this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461376/regex-repeating-capturing-group)

You can use

```
^.([^/]+\/[^/]+)\/(.*)$
```

[image]

```js
let str = `/firstname/lastname/some/cool/name`

let op = str.match(/^.([^/]+\/[^/]+)\/(.*)$/)

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Works. But I don't get why. How did you create this neat little graphic?

Comment: @Stephan where you're facing problem to understand ? this little graphics is generated by [`Regex visualizer`](https://jex.im/regulex/)

Comment: The more I look at it the more clear it is. The only thing missing now is the first two characters: ^. I guess they are used to ignore the first character. But how?

Comment: @Stephan `^` means start of string and `.` means match anything except new line, since we don't want this to be included in our group so we kept it out of `()`

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the first `/`, then capturing the first two words, then capturing the rest of the phrase after the `/`.

```
^(:?\/)([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\/(.+)
```

[See example](https://regexr.com/4he6e)

Answer (score 0):

The quantifier `{3}` repeats 3 times the capturing group, which will have the value of the last iteration.

The first iteration will match `/`, the second `firstname/` and the third (the last iteration) `lastname/` which will be the value of the group.

The second group captures matching `[^.]*` which will match 0+ not a literal dot which does not take the  the structure of the data into account.

If you want to match the full pattern, you could use:

```
^\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\/([^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^\/]+/[^\/]+` Match 2 times not a `/` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) then a `/`
- `)` Close group
- `\/` Match `/`
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `[^\/]+` Match 1+ times not `/`
  - `(?:\/[^\/]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `/` and 1+ times not `/` to match the pattern of the rest of the string.
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtehQH/1)